# Dynamic Image Loading in processing

Tags: image, processing

In a processing drawing loop, I have an algorithm that uses face detection to trigger a picture being taken. However so far I cannot get the image to display in my drawing loop. Does anyone know how to halt a drawing loop until an image is loaded and displayed? Here's the section of my drawing loop:

```
  if (faces.length > 0) {
    save("Source/face.jpg");
    PImage img = loadImage("Source/face.jpg");
    image(img,0,0);
  } else {
    println("not seeing anything");
  }
```

Obviously this isn't working, how do I dynamically load and display images in processing?

Answer (score 0):

I have this function in javascript

```
loadimage: function(image, i) {
var img = new Image();
$(img).load(function () {
       $(this).hide();
       $('#loader'+i).append(this);
       $('#loading'+i).removeClass('image-container-loading');
       $(this).fadeIn();
     }).error(function () {
           // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
     }).attr('src',image).css('width','50px').css('height','50px').css('position','absolute');
  }
```

Called:

```
self.loadimage('http://www.test.com/files/images/hi.jpg,ide);
```

html:

```
<li class='promotion'><span class='image-container' id='loader"+ide+"'>
<span class='units'></span>
<span style='border: solid 0px' class='image-container-loading' id='loading'>
</span></li>
```